# Custom TreeView template to display hiearchical data in "a flow"

Tags: silverlight-4.0, treeview

I have data structured in a hierarchical manner, that when being rendered with the TreeView control gets the output as below to the left. But I want to have the visual appearance looking more like the graph on the right (mockup).
[image: I want the output to the right]

I've tried templating the TreeView and TreeViewItem controls but can't really get anything to work as I would've hoped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done in styles.

I have created one and hopefully you can start from here to achieve what you wanted. :)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CommonValidationToolTipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translation" X="-25"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualTransition>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4,4,-4,-4"/>
            <Border Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3,3,-3,-3"/>
            <Border Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,-2,-2"/>
            <Border Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1,1,-1,-1"/>
            <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" MaxWidth="250" Margin="8,4,8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFB8E2B7" Margin="2,-1,2,2">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Header">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF999999"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Selection"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedInactive">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Selection"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF999999" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionFill"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF333333" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionStroke"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HasItemsStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="HasItems"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoItems">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Validation">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="Validation">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationToolTip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" TabNavigation="Once" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF1BBBFA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="UncheckedVisual"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="UncheckedVisual"/>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedVisual"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid Margin="2">
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedVisual" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stroke="#FF989898" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,5" Width="11" Height="1" Opacity="0"/>
                                                <Path x:Name="UncheckedVisual" Data="M4.9999995,6 L5.9999995,6 L5.9999995,10.5 L4.9999995,10.5 z M5.9999995,5 L10.5,5 L10.5,6 L5.9999995,6 z M0.5,5 L4.9999995,5 L4.9999995,6 L0.5,6 z M4.9999995,0.5 L5.9999995,0.5 L5.9999995,5 L4.9999995,5 z" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF989898" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="11" Height="11"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ToggleButton.Template>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Selection" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" StrokeThickness="1">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="SelectionFill" Color="#FFBADDE9"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="SelectionStroke" Color="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                </Rectangle.Stroke>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Button x:Name="Header" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" ClickMode="Hover" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="False" TabNavigation="Once" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Hover"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="Hover" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                            </Button>
                            <Border x:Name="Validation" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="ValidationToolTip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" IsHitTestVisible="True" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Header}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}"/>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="10" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10">
                                    <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 Z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="-1,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="-1,3,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:TreeView>
        <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem" IsExpanded="True">
            <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem" IsExpanded="True">
                <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem" IsExpanded="True">
                    <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
                    <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem"/>
                </sdk:TreeViewItem>
                <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem" Margin="0"/>
            </sdk:TreeViewItem>
            <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="TreeViewItem" Margin="0"/>
        </sdk:TreeViewItem>
    </sdk:TreeView>
</Grid>
```